# Drupal upgrade 6.20 to 7.0

Tags: drupal-6, upgrade, drupal-7

I am attempting to upgrade my version of drupal from 6.20 to 7.0.  When i try to get to update.php page, i get this error before I even can start the update script:

DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table role_permission already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 630 of /var/www/drupal/includes/database/schema.inc)

Anyone know how to fix this (without removing any tables from my database)?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal.org has a multi-page tutorial on upgrading from Drupal 6 to 7.  You can check it out here: http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/6/7.  I would suggest following that as closely as possible.